# Why does Alex Jones drink whiskey while doing bench push ups?

Tags: plot-explanation, this-place-rules

In the new documentary, this place rules, Andrew is seen doing bench push ups with Alex Jones.

Alex Jones is seen doing bench push ups while drinking whiskey and saying 1776 at the same time.

Why would Alex Jones drink whiskey and doing bench push ups at the same time? Is it his personal ritual?

Comment: So this might have attracted a downvote because this is a documentary and Alex is a real-life person not a character.  Documentary is a legitimate on-topic subject here, but a question about someone's real-life behavior might not be what someone is interested in.  Alex is a media personality who makes money by selling merchandise.  I'm sure his behavior in any context is governed by the image he is trying to project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alex Jones is a talented and successful media personality.  This is not an endorsement of his general behavior or of the content of his shows, just an analysis of his success.  Lawsuits aside he has made himself extremely rich by producing and presenting Radio and TV, and selling a lot of merchandise on the back of that.

As a media personality, I'm sure that everything he does in front of a camera is carefully considered to project the right image to his fans.  Unless a documentary is capturing this behavior entirely secretly, he's doing this for the camera and the people that love him and support him by watching and buying his product.

So, the short answer is: This is behavior that he wants to project to his fans.  He thinks they will admire him, or find it funny.

Answer (score 1):

I know it now. Alex Jones has had a brand of sport supplement with a patroic theme called 1776.

That is why he keeps saying 1776, as a way to promote his own products.

Comment: Yes. As you allude to, and @iandotkelly describes in more detail, Alex Jones is fundamentally in the business of direct-selling diet supplements and political merchandise to viewers. He is a salesman, and everything he says and does in his public life is best understood from that perspective.

Comment: @Tom, yeah, definitely. I am not familar with Alex Jones, as he is prodominately a public figure in the USA.